# Joystick acts as mouse; won't stop

Tags: 10.10, xorg, input-devices, gamepad, joystick

Joystick acts as a mouse, even when I'm playing a game that uses a joystick so I get random mouse events going on.

I plugged a joystick in to play Spiral Knights, also installed joystick and jcalibrate. Everything is working good, except by default the joystick moves the mouse around and the button activate mouse keys.

Now normally this would be good behavior if I'm on a Myth-box or something, unfortunately when I play Spiral Knights with joystick input I see my mouse cursor moving in the back ground and when I hit a button it thinks I'm pressing right-click so it minimizes everything. Also it creates folders and probably deletes stuff.

So, basically how the heck do I stop it from acting as a mouse?

Comment: Can you show what PC you have and joystick you are using. Also what Ubuntu version.

Comment: I'm using a playstation 2 to usb adapter, under the jscalibrate it's listed as: GreenAsia Inc. USB Joystick. I'm running Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Uninstall `xserver-xorg-input-joystick`.

It's a package to control the mouse with the joystick. I only installed once to test it and it was driving me mad, so maybe that's the problem. I think the joystick would work the same without it.

Comment: Hooray that did it! I think that got tacked on when I added the joystick package in synaptic. It works great now!

Comment: I had this problem also and it fixed it. Many thanks for answering, much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to turn off/on this feaature? Is kindda cool controling the mouse with the gamepad but it should be nice to turn it on when i do need it

Comment: thank's darent, this worked on Arch Linux too! Was trying to play Dustforce, and this was really annoying me.

Comment: FYI I had to log out and back in also. And in Manjaro linux, the package name was xf86-input-joystick.

Answer (score 6):

put this code in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
id=`xinput list | grep "↳ DragonRise Inc.   Generic   USB  Joystick     id=" | cut -c58-59`
props_mouse=`xinput list-props $id | grep "Generate Mouse Events (" | cut -c25-27`
props_teclado=`xinput list-props $id | grep "Generate Key Events (" | cut -c23-25`
xinput set-prop $id $props_mouse 0
xinput set-prop $id $props_teclado 0
```

save it, right button in rights and tick "mark this file as a program"

execute it and you will have your joystick "as joystick again"
(and the best, you can have your joystick as mouse again if you change the "0" in the last two lines with "1").

Comment: It looks like the format of the "xinput list" lines have changed.

Comment: This code need changes to work under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  The output has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Linux Mint 17.3 and I was having this same problem.  I had the on-live console and I was going to throw away the controller. I didn't know it would work, but It connected easily through bluetooth. The left joystick was controlling the mouse and I search and try different methods but none of them worked. I'm posting this so it can help other people.  I followed the fix from the Ubuntu [Sixaxis](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sixaxis#Disable_Joystick_From_Controlling_Mouse) setup page.  I had to add this configuration to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "joystick catchall"
    MatchIsJoystick "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "joystick"
    Option "StartKeysEnabled" "False"   # Disable mouse
    Option "StartMouseEnabled" "False"  # support
EndSection
```

It works perfectly after logging out.  The only problem is if the xorg.conf is updated like after installing a new graphics driver, it will lose it.  Can someone explain me how to create a script that checks the configuration is in the file, if not, write it after each reboot?  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: On deb based systems files in '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/' are treated as part of xorg.conf which avoids the update issues.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, but with a Playstation 3 controller. Using the answers as a template, I expanded on the solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
id=`xinput list | grep -P "PLAYSTATION.*pointer" | grep -oP "id=\d+" | grep -oP "\d+"`
props=`xinput list-props $id`
# echo "$props"
props_mouse=(`echo "$props" | grep "Generate Mouse Events" | grep -oP "\d+"`)
props_keyboard=(`echo "$props" | grep "Generate Key Events" | grep -oP "\d+"`)
xinput set-prop $id ${props_mouse[0]} $[1-${props_mouse[1]}]
xinput set-prop $id ${props_keyboard[0]} $[1-${props_mouse[1]}]
```

This version of the script will enable or disable the controller, depending on the current settings, like a toggle.

Comment: Because this is a new solution for a) a different controller and b) has different functionality to the given scripts. I don't see how editing an existing answer would change that.

Comment: Good enough for me!  Upvoted so it'll rise to the top!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

You perhaps should be using jscal to calibrate your joystick - you can use the -u option as per the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/jscal.1.html#contenttoc5) to configure the joystick to not use the mouse buttons.

There is some interesting stuff about the various joysticks & gamepads on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=338457) as well.

Comment: Is there a way to configure this without generating then editing an xorg.conf file? (I'm already using jscal to calibrate the joystick)

Comment: I use jstest-gtk it's in the repos i think.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Qjoypad](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/) or (if you don't want to use QT) the slighlty less featured [rejoystick](http://rejoystick.sourceforge.net/) (GTK). This way you don't have to edit/create xorg.conf.

They both are available on [playdeb](http://www.playdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/10.04/?q=joy)

Understanding joystick drivers is kind of a mess, everything seems to be either outdated or unfinished... Good luck!

Comment: These are great programs but unfortunately didn't solve my problem as rebinding them didn't make the issue go away.

Answer (score 0):

1- You should see your joystick number first ... so Run Terminal and type xinpute list ,and look to your joystick number and replace its number instead of the 10 in the Example below.

```
#!/bin/bash id=xinput list | grep "↳ DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick id=10" | cut -c58-59 props_mouse=xinput list-props 10 | grep "Generate Mouse Events (" | cut -c25-27 props_teclado=xinput list-props 10 | grep "Generate Key Events (" | cut -c23-25 xinput set-prop 10 $props_mouse 0 xinput set-prop 10 $props_teclado 0
```

2- Creat a new Document then put the code in it , then rename it to name.sh Format 3- Run Terminal then put the path where you save the file .

Example : cd Desktop (Because i saved mine on the Desktop)

4- Type bash name.sh ( Click Enter and You are Done ! )

Note1: to Turn it back on just change the 0 on the last 2 lines to 1 Note2: if this doesn't work make sure to remove xserver-xorg-input-joystick and /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-joystick

Answer (score 0):

Matias Parmigiani's answer was the key for me. However, the format of the `xinput list` has changed, at least on Ubuntu 13.04 LTS...

```
⎜   ↳ DragonRise Inc.   Generic   USB  Joystick     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ↳ DragonRise Inc.   Generic   USB  Joystick   (keys)    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As a result I needed to use the following in my disablement script:

```
#!/bin/bash
id=`xinput list | grep -P "DragonRise Inc.   Generic   USB  Joystick\s+id=" | grep -oP "id=\d+"| cut -c4-5`
props_mouse=`xinput list-props $id | grep "Generate Mouse Events" | grep -oP "\(\d+"| cut -c2-5`
props_teclado=`xinput list-props $id | grep "Generate Key Events" | grep -oP "\(\d+"| cut -c2-5`
xinput set-prop "$id" "$props_mouse" 0
xinput set-prop "$id" "$props_teclado" 0
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I Have Linuxlite version 4.8 and the solution I found was very simple. Settings-> Mouse and Touchpad-> Devices-> Choose your joypad device and then disable it. No fancy scripts and whatnot. In my case it was a USB converted SNES controller.
Hope this helps for someone!