# My joypad acting like a mouse

Tags: uninstall, joystick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Joystick acts as mouse; won't stop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33672/joystick-acts-as-mouse-wont-stop)

I've a problem, my joypad actually acting like a mouse, and doesn't work with torcs game, somebody know how to make it working properly?

Comment: Is your problem isolated to the game only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of controller would probably help here. But if your controller has a dual mode (you can select from analog and digital) make sure it is set to Analog. Also make sure the controller is calibrated.

Comment: When you say that it acts like a mouse I imagine that it keeps traveling in a certain direction after it is released which why I suggest to make sure it is in analog mode.

Comment: the controller is calibrated, it's dual mode and setted on analog, i'm using it with rFactor under playonlinux with no problems, but on the desktop it can move the mouse pointer and acting like a mouse, for this I think it don't work in Torcs i see the mouse pointer moving in the game and the joypad don't give input to the game like a joypad bu like a mouse...

Comment: I found this for you. Let me know if it works please. http://askubuntu.com/questions/33672/joystick-acts-as-mouse-wont-stop

Comment: solved with 'code' sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-joystick