# Bluetooth manager adds gamepad to xinput Virtual Core Pointer every time I connect it on Xubuntu 15.04

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, bluetooth, 15.10, gamepad

I've had success on my previous version of Xubuntu (14.04) adding a Wii U Pro Controller simply using by using the bluetooth manager and selecting "Proceed without pairing" -> "Device successfully added" which seemed to add it perfectly fine and it would work in most games right away.

I upgraded to 15.10. Now it won't work if I use the old method, but it will if I select "create random passkey" -> "connect human interface device". Only problem is the gamepad starts controlling the mouse. If I push the left stick to the right, the mouse goes to the rightmost edge of the screen. If I leave it in the middle, it goes to the middle. Which is frustrating because with the slightest bump it will reset the mouse position to the middle as long as it's connected, and games which use the mouse to control the camera have the camera going all over the place.

I check "xinput list" and it gives this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Optical USB Mouse                id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K230                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Nintendo Wii Remote Pro Controller        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling xserver-xorg-input-joystick (it was never installed)
- Phoeey and Matias Parmigiani's answers from [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33672/joystick-acts-as-mouse-wont-stop) (It returns an error of:

  ```
  invalid property ''
  invalid property ''
  ```
- Ulao's response from [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1879616). The first suggestion works, but I have to do it every time I connect the device. The second suggestion doesn't work because the file doesn't exist on my system.
- Mark Bower's response from the page above also works but I have to re-do it every time I connect the gamepad, too.

Any other suggestions?