# Disabling mouse movement from left joystick on PS3 controller?

Tags: mouse, joystick, ps3

I installed `antimicro`, which allows me to configure my PS3 controller (USB plugged). While my left joystick's mappings work as expected, it *also* moves the mouse, which is the "default" behavior for it (i.e. it does that even if I don't have `antimicro` installed). How can I disable this default behavior and only use the mapping provided by `antimicro`?

Comment: I have already tried the solution posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/33672/joystick-acts-as-mouse-wont-stop?rq=1 it says I don't have the `xserver-xorg-input-joystick` installed.

Comment: I also found something like this, but it's for Arch and seems like neither my Linux Mint nor Ubuntu has these packages: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119421

Comment: I think that the package from ARCH page is equivalent of `xserver...joystick`. Did you try adding profile to xorg.conf ala [arch-answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=937336#p937336) or [ubuntu-answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/705591/385584) ?

Answer (score 1):

So many people have had this issue and I finally figure it out!

1. Type `xinput` into a terminal and find the id for the controller
2. Type `xinput disable ID` into the terminal, but replace `ID` with the actual ID

The controller will no longer control the mouse cursor, but should work just fine for normal usage. I have only tested this method with Steam, but it worked fine there and I have no reason to believe it would be any different elsewhere.